Add prefix to beginning of string in postgres
I have a table in a postgres database with data that looks like this:
XX-001111111-11-Q011111o_ABC_90001u-0000101-9
The table has 1000 rows with similar looking strings.
I want to update every row to add the AB- prefix to it.
So XX-001111111-11-Q011111o_ABC_90001u-0000101-9 would look like
AB-XX-001111111-11-Q011111o_ABC_90001u-0000101-9
I assume I can do this with regex_replace but everything I've tried has not worked.

You don't need a regex. Just do an UPDATE and set the column (COL) with 'AB' + COL. I don't know what the concatenation operator is in PostgreSQL, but use it in place of + if that's not the operator. An example for SQL Server would be UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = 'AB' + MyCOL

Maybe use a simple view instead of updating? create view the_view as select 'AB-' || the_column as the_column, ... from the_table;

You don't need a regex operation to change the value (prefix a string) of a column. An example using psql shell:
-- Create a table and insert a row with a string column
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  my_string VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('XX-001111111-11-Q011111o_ABC_90001u-0000101-9');

-- Query the table
SELECT * FROM t1;
                   my_string
-----------------------------------------------
 XX-001111111-11-Q011111o_ABC_90001u-0000101-9

-- Update the table column value
UPDATE t1 SET my_string = concat('AB-', my_string);

-- Query the table to see the updated column value
SELECT * FROM t1;
                   my_string
-------------------------------------------------
 AB-XX-001111111-11-Q011111o_ABC_90001u-0000101-9

The concat is a PostgreSQL string function. You can also use the || (concatenation operator) to produce the same result:
UPDATE t1 SET my_string = 'AB-' || my_string;

Refrerence: PostgreSQL String Functions and Operators

Assume:

your table Name is Test1
your column name is sname

SQL:
UPDATE Test1
SET sname = 'AB-' || sname;

I tested it in my environment and it can be executed successfully.
PostgreSQL 16.3 (Debian 16.3-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit

You can use CONCAT which enhances readability and clearly conveys the intent of the operation:
here you go , an example:
UPDATE your_table_name
SET your_column_name = CONCAT('AB-', your_column_name);

